# Issue with FilePond when adding files using jQuery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, filepond

Don't use JQ and file pond upload file

I'm facing an issue with FilePond while attempting to add files to the input field using jQuery. Here is my code:

```
var inputDesc = document.getElementById("inpImgDesc");
FilePond.create(inputDesc, {
    allowMultiple: true,
    labelIdle: 'Kéo & Thả hoặc Click để chọn tệp',
    labelFileProcessing: 'Đang xử lý tệp...',
    labelFileProcessingComplete: 'Xử lý hoàn tất',
    acceptedFileTypes: ['image/*'],
    imagePreviewMaxHeight: 300,
    imagePreviewMaxWidth: 300,
});
```

And I've tried a few methods to add files to FilePond:

```
Method 1:
var pond = FilePond.find(document.getElementById('inpImgDesc'));
$.get("http://localhost:8080/photo?realEstateId=" + paramProject).then(function(photos){
    photos.forEach(photo => {
        var parts = photo.path.split('/');
        var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1]
        $.get("http://localhost:8080" + photo.path).then(function(response) {
            var file = new File([response], fileName);
            pond.addFile(file);
        });
    });
});
Method 2:
var pond = FilePond.find(document.getElementById('inpImgDesc'));
$.get("http://localhost:8080/photo?realEstateId=" + paramProject).then(function(photos){
    photos.forEach(photo => {
        const file = {
            source: "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/realestate/src/main/resources/static" + photo.path,
            options: {
                type: 'local', // This is a local path
            },
        };
        pond.addFile(file);
    });
});
Method 3:
Copy code
$.get("http://localhost:8080/photo?realEstateId=" + paramProject).then(function(photos){
    photos.forEach(photo => {
        const file = {
            source: photo.path,
            options: {
                type: 'local', // This is a local path
            },
        };
        pond.addFile(file);
    });
});
```

It here result $.get("http://localhost:8080/photo?realEstateId=" + paramProject)
`[ { "id": 9, "path": "/images/Project/125/imgDesc/property-14.jpg" }, { "id": 10, "path": "/images/Project/125/imgDesc/property-17.jpg" }, { "id": 11, "path": "/images/Project/125/imgDesc/property-42.jpg" }, { "id": 12, "path": "/images/Project/125/imgDesc/property-44.jpg" }, { "id": 13, "path": "/images/Project/125/imgDesc/property-46.jpg" } ]`
I did try test src=> src correct
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsHRX.png)